# Retrieving CSV fields and also raw string from file simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator that yields rows from a CSV file one at a time, something like:

```py
import csv

def as_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        yield from csv.reader(fin)
```

However, I need to *also* capture the raw string returned from the file, as this needs to be persisted at the same time.

As far as I can tell, the `csv` built-in can be used on an ad-hoc basis, something like this:

```py
import csv

def as_csv_and_raw(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for row in fin:
            raw = row.strip()
            values = csv.reader([raw])[0]
       yield (values, raw)
```

... but this has the overhead of creating a new reader and a new iterable for each row of the file, so on files with millions of rows I'm concerned about the performance impact.

It feels like I could create a coroutine that could interact with the primary function, yielding the parsed fields in a way where I can control the input directly without losing it, something like this:

```py
import csv

def as_csv_and_raw(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        reader = raw_to_csv(some_coroutine())
        reader.next()
        for row in fin:
            raw = row.strip()
            fields = reader.send(raw)
            yield fields, raw

def raw_to_csv(data):
    yield from csv.reader(data)

def some_coroutine():
    # what goes here?
    raise NotImplementedError
```

I haven't really wrapped my head around coroutines and using `yield` as an expression, so I'm not sure what goes in `some_coroutine`, but the intent is that each time I `send` a value in, that value is run through the `csv.reader` object and I get the set of fields back.

Can someone provide the implementation of `some_coroutine`, or alternately show me a better mechanism for getting the desired data?

Comment: Not sure if it may work for your implementation needs, but have you considered using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package?

Comment: While `pandas` is awesome in general, for this particular purpose the driving motivator is performance, so I'm trying to use as few layers of complexity as possible. However, if I get a chance I might run a performance evaluation to see if it might work. I suspect I can find everything in need in `builtins`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to create two independent iterators from the iterable file object, create a `csv.reader` from one of them, and then zip the other iterator with it for output:

```
from itertools import tee

def as_csv_and_raw(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        row, raw = tee(fin)
        yield from zip(csv.reader(row), raw)
```

Comment: Perfect! I've never used `tee` and so it didn't occur to me. Thanks!